# Database structure in Django for voting app

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I would structure my database tables in the Django webapp I'm writing.  I'm a relative newbie to web development, but this is the very first time I've tried to use a database, so bear with me if it's a stupid question.

The webapp goes through each Oscar the Academy gives out and allows the user to select which of some (varying) number of nominations will win an Oscar.  The data from each individual session will be publicly available by going to a url like [url].com/answers/[unique id].  The overall data will also be available on a results page.  So I've started writing my models file, and this is what I have so far:

```
    from django.db import models

    class Nominee(models.Model):
      award = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      key = modelsCharField(max_length=50)
      subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      numVotes = models.IntegerField()

    class Session(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField() # unique id of visitor
      bpictureVote = models.ForeignKey(Nominee, related_name = 'nom')
      bactorVote = models.ForeignKey(Nominee, related_name = 'nom')
      # ... for each award
```

I was originally thinking of having

```
    class Award(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and at the beginning of Nominee,

```
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award, related_name = 'award')
```

but I couldn't figure out why that would be better than just having award be a part of the Nominee class.

This is really just a start, because I've gotten a bit stuck.  Am I on the right track?  Should I be doing this totally differently (as I probably should...)?  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I was thinking about this entirely wrong.  I've now completely changed things, and now it's fully functional (!).  But in the spirit of full disclosure, I should say that it definitely may not be the best solution.  It sure seems like a good one, though, because it's really simple.  Now I have only one model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    award = models.CharField(...)    # Name of the award
    title = models.CharField(...)    # Title of the nominee
    subtitle = models.CharField(...) # Subtitle of the nominee
    uid = models.CharField(...)      # A 6 character user ID for future access
```

When I want to show the results of one user's votes, I can use Django's database tools to filter for a certain uid captured in the URL.  When I want to tally the votes, I can use a combination of filters and Django's count() to determine how many votes each nominee had for a certain award.  Sounds reasonable enough to me!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

You need a separate Award class to avoid having to type in award's name every time you create a Nominee. By having a ForeignKey reference you make sure that you can safely rename your award, add additional information about the award (let's say in the future you decide to give each award a separate page with a description and a list of nominees), you also avoid errors which can happen from having a set of different spellings and typos ("Best Engineer Award" and "Best Engineer award"). It also makes sense - your application operates a set of objects: user sessions, nominees and awards.

Few unrelated notes:

- You don't need an explicit Session.id field, django ORM creates it for you.
- Property names have to be name_with_underscores, not camelCase.
- No spaces around "=" in an arguments list: `models.ForeignKey(Nominee, related_name='nom')`.
- 4 spaces instead of 2 (unless explicitly otherwise specified).

Comment: Okay, so I was thinking about this wrong. I have a fixed number of awards (24), each with an arbitrary (but known) number of nominees (3-9 or so). These are not dynamically generated by the user. Rather, the user is voting on which nominee he thinks should win the award. I've changed things around so that I have a Vote class with a couple of fields identifying what the vote is for (the award and the nominee). I'll use count() on a filter to determine how many of each vote I have. Then I should be able to ForeignKey the session data to those Votes. Does that sound reasonable? Thanks!

Comment: @airplanemania Think of your application in terms of objects. Your application operates Awards, Nominees and Users. This means it's reasonable to have separate models for all three objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, because you do mention multiple nominees per award (assuming this is something like a poll before the actual nomination) a ManyToMany would be your required relation, in order to use also the additional user data.
But in the case you have implemented this as a specific app for nominations and implemented a custom user model then this would be refactored to something else...
Anyway to your current implementation:

```
class Nominee(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    key = modelsCharField(max_length=50)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class Award(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nominees = models.ManyToManyField(Nominee, through='AwardNominees')
    ...

class AwardNominees(models.Model):
    nominee = models.ForeignKey(Nominee)
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    numVotes = models.IntegerField()
    ....
```